# Way to jump between marks?

Tags: sublimetext3, sublimetext

I know you can create marks at lines using `Edit -> Mark -> Set Mark` but is it possible to go to previous Mark, next Mark, etc. without manually finding it?

Also how do you use the commands for the Mark which are separated by commas: e.g. command K, command space to set mark. Just pressing them sequentially will not work

EDIT: just realized you can only set 1 mark per document. Is there another feature in Sublime that I might be looking for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't used it, but [`MarkAndMove`](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/MarkAndMove) may be useful. It looks like you can set multiple marks and move between them, amongst other features.

For chording commands like <kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>K</kbd>,<kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>Space</kbd>, hold down the <kbd>⌘</kbd> key, hit <kbd>K</kbd>, release <kbd>K</kbd> while still holding down <kbd>⌘</kbd>, then hit <kbd>Space</kbd>.

Comment: Thanks that works. I can jump between lines easily now but it seems I have to use the default Mark feature to highlight multiple lines. Basically reapply the default mark at the last line that i want to highlight, navigate to my last mark (placed with MarkAndMove) and use command K, command A to highlight the block.